# how to trigger the browser geo location request again after clicked allow

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geocoding

Its more for web development, I wonder once a user clicked yes on the browser's location request, then refresh the same page, it does not prompt again. I wonder what is the thing that control if its going to prompt again? Is there way to allow the prompt to trigger again with javascript?

for example the prompt looks like this in safari
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956500/how-to-expire-or-reset-geolocation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014154/how-do-i-reset-the-geolocation-service-settings-each-time-my-page-loads-in-html5, http://superuser.com/questions/591758/how-do-i-make-chrome-forget-a-no-to-geolocation-on-a-site

Comment: @Nate this one http://superuser.com/questions/591758/how-do-i-make-chrome-forget-a-no-to-geolocation-on-a-site helped! thanks!